# "Qu'à cela ne tienne" au passé simple

Tags: expressions, conjugaison, passé-simple

Cette expression peut-elle se dire au passé, temps usuel pour l'écriture?

Par exemple : "ils ne trouvèrent pas de restaurants, qu'à cela ne **tint**, ils se mangèrent entre eux"

ou alors : "ils n'avaient pas trouvé de discothèque, qu'à cela n'avait tenu, ils avaient chanté eux mêmes" ...

Comment: Voulez-vous vraiment dire: _ils se mangèrent entre eux_, ou bien est-ce une erreur? Ce serait une erreur ... succulente. Je ne sais pas quel est votre niveau de français, mais vous avez écrit, si je traduis en anglais: _they ate themselves_ :-) Did you mean: _ils mangèrent entre eux_, which means: _they ate by themselves_, roughly.

Comment: Je suis un francophone à l'humour noir douteux. Je voulais bien écrire ce que j'ai écrit :P

Comment: How can you take a present ***subjunctive*** (tienne) and then use the passé simple?? That would  not be grammatical in French. ***Qu'à cela n'ait tenu***,  enfin. "à l'humour noir et au verbe défaillant?" :) Il faut mettre le verbe ***tenir*** au passé du subjontif, dit-elle avec une certaine ironie. C'est la moindre des choses....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

« *Qu'à cela ne tienne* » est une locution proverbiale figée.

Il n'est donc pas possible<sup>1</sup> d'en modifier le temps ou quoi que ce soit, ce qui ne pose d'ailleurs aucun problème dans les textes envisagés :

> Ils ne trouvèrent pas de restaurant. Qu'à cela ne tienne ! Ils se mangèrent entre eux [*sic*].
>
> Ils n'avaient pas trouvé de discothèque. Qu'à cela ne tienne ! Ils avaient chanté eux-mêmes.

Voici un exemple d'utilisation de cette locution dans une phrase à l'imparfait par *Jacques Savoie*, Un train de glace, chap. 3, p 45:

[image]

<sup>1</sup> Vous démontrez le contraire puisque Chateaubriand l'a fait.

Dans l'expression « Je lui répondis qu’à cela ne tenait », il ne s'agit plus tout à fait de la locution mais de sa retranscription, la phrase originale étant :

> Je lui répondis « – Qu'à cela ne tienne ! »

Comme on aurait pu écrire

> Je lui répondis qu'à quelque chose malheur était bon

pour

> Je lui répondis « – À quelque chose malheur est bon »

La concordance des temps s'impose alors sur le reste.

Comment: Merci ! C'est ce que je pensais aussi mais je n'arrive pas à trouver une source qui le confirme... Tous les exemples d'utilisation que je trouve sont au présent ! En auriez-vous une ?

Comment: Ah... C'est vrai que mon Chateaubriand était du discours rapporté... Je continue à chercher... Surtout que ma source étant vieille et le langage étant en constante évolution, il ne serait pas aberrant que l'usage soit aujourd'hui fixé même s'il ne l'était pas avant... J'espère que l'académie ne va pas me répondre "gna gna gna gna pauv' c%#*"... Espérons que ça ne soit pas Finkielkraut qui lise les emails. à suivre donc!

Answer (score 2):

En cherchant avec des requêtes un peu plus poussées, j'ai trouvé quelques sources journalistiques de "qu'à cela ne tenait", auxquelles je ne fais pas forcément confiance, mais j'ai aussi trouvé du Chateaubriand qui disait dans *Mémoires d’outre-tombe* :

> Que si mes deux amis voulaient entrer au conseil comme ministres
>   d’État sans portefeuille, le roi en serait charmé, promettant mieux
>   pour la suite. Elle ajoutait que si je consentais à m’éloigner, je
>   serais envoyé à Berlin. Je lui répondis **qu’à cela ne tenait** ; que
>   quant à moi j’étais toujours prêt à partir et que j’irais chez le
>   diable, dans le cas que les rois eussent quelque mission à remplir
>   auprès de leur cousin ; mais que je n’acceptais pourtant un exil que
>   si M. de Villèle acceptait son entrée au conseil. J’aurais voulu aussi
>   placer M. Lainé auprès de mes deux amis. Je me chargeai de la triple
>   négociation.

Je ne suis toujours pas totalement convaincu, je vais contacter l’académie française...

Comment: +1 il fallait le trouver !

Answer (score 0):

Je ne crois pas avoir jamais entendu cette expression au passé. Je crois même qu'on pourrait l'utiliser au présent dans les exemples que vous donnez.